# Finding The Largest Digit in a Number using a Recursive Function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I tried it using the code given below.

```
big=0 ; c=0
def largest(n):
    global c
    c+=1
    global big
    if n//10!=0:
        if big<n%10:
            big=n%10
        return largest(n//10)
    if n//10==0:
        if c==1:
            return n
        else:
            return big
```

But, when I input more than one number in which the first number has the digit of all of them, then the output is the largest digit of the first number, which is repeated.

> For example:
>   If i input 3 numbers like

```
259, 33, 26
```

Then the output will be:

```
9
9
9
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Because big is a global which never resets

Comment: Does it need to be recursive? Why not just cast to string split all and sort

Comment: This is a homework from school, so I have to use recursion. If big never resets, how do I fix that?

Comment: As presented, the code does not work as intended: [off-topic at CodeReview@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Get this working with `reduce` and then converting to an, honestly really poor use of recursion, is easy.

Comment: Ok, suppose I want to convert it into a not really poor use of recursion, then how do I do it?

Comment: You need an inner function that takes the biggest digit up to now and the number as parameters, and calls itself with the maximum of the biggest digit up to now and the current digit, and the number divided by 10, until the number is 0. Sorry, I don't do Python very well; in F# this might look as follows (please excuse the one-liner due to the comment not supporting line breaks): ``let largestDigit n = let rec inner d n = if n = 0 then d else inner (max (n % 10) d) (n / 10) in inner 0 (abs n)``

Comment: @AritraPal a better use of recursion would be: a function which takes two params (n, biggestSoFar = 0)
0. if n == "" return biggestSoFar
1. Otherwise take the first digit of n (maybe use strings for simplicity). And pass the rest to the function again and max of (biggest and the firstNumber taken)

Comment: @AritraPal as greybeard said, its off-topic here at code-review since your function does not work. This forum is only helping in improving working code, try other forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out, this question is off-topic here because this channel is for reviewing and improving code that works as designed. That said, an easy recursive solution using a normal outer function with a recursive inner function could look as follows:

```
def largestDigit(n):
    def inner(d, n):
        if n == 0:
            return d
        else:
            return inner(max(d, n % 10), n // 10)
    return inner(0, abs(n))
```

**Edit:** To keep with the topic of improving working code, here is a shorter version using an `if` expression instead of an `if` statement:

```
def largestDigit(n):
    def inner(d, n):
        return d if n == 0 else inner(max(d, n % 10), n // 10)
    return inner(0, abs(n))
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering off-topic questions. There are plenty of on-topic questions that could use a review.